# Join multiple tables related by a comma-separated list of IDs

Tags: sql-server

FeePreference table:

```
Id  Name    FeeParticularIdList     BatchId
    157 NewStudentOnly  838 77
    158 NewStudentOnly  849 78
    159 NewStudentOnly  860 79
    160 NewStudentOnly  871 80
    161 ExistingStudentOnly 881 82
    162 NewStudentOnly  882 82
    163 ExistingStudentOnly 947 83
    164 NewStudentOnly  948 83
    165 ExistingStudentOnly 947,958 84
    166 NewStudentOnly  948,959 84
    167 ExistingStudentOnly 947,958,969 162
    168 NewStudentOnly  948,959,970 162
    169 ExistingStudentOnly 947,958,969,980 85
```

FeeParticular table

```
Id  Name    Description Amount  FeeCategoryId   IsDeleted   StartDate   EndDate DueDate SortOrder   CreatedAt   UpdatedAt
1454    APRIL (NEW)     16900.00    133 0   2018-04-01 00:00:00.000 2018-04-30 00:00:00.000 2018-12-01 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.543 2018-03-05 17:02:14.543
1455    MAY - JUNE      3400.00 133 0   2018-05-01 00:00:00.000 2018-06-30 00:00:00.000 2018-12-01 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.543 2018-03-05 17:02:14.543
1456    JULY        1700.00 133 0   2018-07-01 00:00:00.000 2018-07-31 00:00:00.000 2018-07-16 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.543 2018-03-05 17:02:14.543
1457    AUGUST      1700.00 133 0   2018-08-01 00:00:00.000 2018-08-31 00:00:00.000 2018-08-16 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.543 2018-03-05 17:02:14.543
1458    SEPTEMBER       1700.00 133 0   2018-09-01 00:00:00.000 2018-09-30 00:00:00.000 2018-09-15 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.543 2018-03-05 17:02:14.543
1459    OCTOBER     1700.00 133 0   2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 2018-10-31 00:00:00.000 2018-10-15 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.543 2018-03-05 17:02:14.543
1460    NOVEMBER        1700.00 133 0   2018-11-01 00:00:00.000 2018-11-30 00:00:00.000 2018-11-15 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.543 2018-03-05 17:02:14.543
1461    DECEMBER        1700.00 133 0   2018-12-01 00:00:00.000 2018-12-31 00:00:00.000 2018-12-15 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.543 2018-03-05 17:02:14.543
1462    JANUARY     1700.00 133 0   2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 2019-01-31 00:00:00.000 2019-01-15 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.543 2018-03-05 17:02:14.543
1463    FEBRUARY - MARCH        3400.00 133 0   2019-02-01 00:00:00.000 2019-03-31 00:00:00.000 2019-03-01 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.543 2018-03-05 17:02:14.543
1464    APRIL (OLD)     9900.00 134 0   2018-04-01 00:00:00.000 2018-04-30 00:00:00.000 2018-12-01 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.580 2018-03-05 17:02:14.580
1465    APRIL (NEW)     16900.00    134 0   2018-04-01 00:00:00.000 2018-04-30 00:00:00.000 2018-12-01 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.580 2018-03-05 17:02:14.580
1466    MAY - JUNE      3400.00 134 0   2018-05-01 00:00:00.000 2018-06-30 00:00:00.000 2018-12-01 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.580 2018-03-05 17:02:14.580
1467    JULY        1700.00 134 0   2018-07-01 00:00:00.000 2018-07-31 00:00:00.000 2018-07-16 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.580 2018-03-05 17:02:14.580
1468    AUGUST      1700.00 134 0   2018-08-01 00:00:00.000 2018-08-31 00:00:00.000 2018-08-16 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.580 2018-03-05 17:02:14.580
1469    SEPTEMBER       1700.00 134 0   2018-09-01 00:00:00.000 2018-09-30 00:00:00.000 2018-09-15 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.580 2018-03-05 17:02:14.580
1470    OCTOBER     1700.00 134 0   2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 2018-10-31 00:00:00.000 2018-10-15 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.580 2018-03-05 17:02:14.580
1471    NOVEMBER        1700.00 134 0   2018-11-01 00:00:00.000 2018-11-30 00:00:00.000 2018-11-15 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.580 2018-03-05 17:02:14.580
1472    DECEMBER        1700.00 134 0   2018-12-01 00:00:00.000 2018-12-31 00:00:00.000 2018-12-15 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.580 2018-03-05 17:02:14.580
1473    JANUARY     1700.00 134 0   2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 2019-01-31 00:00:00.000 2019-01-15 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.580 2018-03-05 17:02:14.580
1474    FEBRUARY - MARCH        3400.00 134 0   2019-02-01 00:00:00.000 2019-03-31 00:00:00.000 2019-03-01 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.580 2018-03-05 17:02:14.580
1475    APRIL (OLD)     9900.00 135 0   2018-04-01 00:00:00.000 2018-04-30 00:00:00.000 2018-12-01 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.627 2018-03-05 17:02:14.627
1476    APRIL (NEW)     16900.00    135 0   2018-04-01 00:00:00.000 2018-04-30 00:00:00.000 2018-12-01 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.627 2018-03-05 17:02:14.627
1477    MAY - JUNE      3400.00 135 0   2018-05-01 00:00:00.000 2018-06-30 00:00:00.000 2018-12-01 00:00:00.000 NULL    2018-03-05 17:02:14.627 2018-03-05 17:02:14.627
```

FeeCategory table:

```
Id  Name    Description BatchId IsDeleted   SortOrder   CreatetdAt  UpdatedAt
59  MONTHLY FEE     12  0   NULL    2018-01-05 20:48:05.673 2018-01-05 20:48:05.673
60  MONTHLY FEE     63  0   NULL    2018-01-05 20:48:05.673 2018-01-05 20:48:05.673
61  MONTHLY FEE     64  0   NULL    2018-01-05 20:48:05.673 2018-01-05 20:48:05.673
62  MONTHLY FEE     65  0   NULL    2018-01-05 20:48:05.673 2018-01-05 20:48:05.673
```

If a student is Existing, then only select the existing particulars with all other non-defined fee particulars for the specific Student.

Otherwise, select the new fee particulars with all other non-defined fee particulars.

How do I write a query to meet these requirements?

Comment: I assume `FeePreference.FeeParticularIdList` is a comma separated list of values from `FeeParticular.Id`? That's bad design. If you have any chance to change the schema here, drop that column `FeePreference.FeeParticularIdList` and create a table with two columns referencing `FeePreference.Id`and `FeeParticular.Id` to model that list in a native relational way. Otherwise it's impossible to do queries on that in plain SQL and use foreign key constraints to ensure referential integrity.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is join `FeePreference` and `FeeParticular`.  This is difficult, because the keys to `FeeParticular` are stored as a list of comma-separated values in the `FeePreference` table (which is a bad idea, more on that later).

If you're using SQL 2016 or newer, you can use the [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to accomplish this.

<sub>If you're using an older version of SQL Server, you should consider updating.  Otherwise, you'll need to use one of these less-than-ideal solutions: [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)</sub>

```
select *
from FeePreference pref
    inner join FeeParticular part
        on part.Id in (select * from string_split(pref.FeeParticularIdList, ','))
```

This is all preferences matched to all particulars.  Regarding the filtering requirements you mentioned:

> If student is Existing then only existing particular with all other non defined fee particular for specific Student

When you say "existing particular and all other non-defined fee particular" I think you mean "existing" preferences should match any particular that doesn't include "(NEW)" in its name.

> else new fee particular with all other non defined fee particular

Which makes me think that "New" preferences should have particulars that don't include "(OLD)" in their name.

All of that can be included in the join predicate:

```
select *
from FeePreference pref
    inner join FeeParticular part
        -- this line matches each preference to all of the particulars in their list
        on part.Id in (select * from string_split(pref.FeeParticularIdList, ','))
        and 
        (
            -- this filters the matching so that "existing" preferences don't get "new" particulars
            (pref.[Name] = 'ExistingStudentOnly' and part.[Name] not like '% (NEW)')
            or
            -- this filters the matching so that "new" preferences don't get "old" particulars
            (pref.[Name] = 'NewStudentOnly' and part.[Name] not like '% (OLD)')
        )
order by pref.Id;
```

*Note: your example dataset doesn't include any "particulars" that match any "preferences," so I can't test that this works with the specific data you included.*

---

By the way, a more idiomatic design would have a "mapping table" that defines this relationship (instead of the comma-separated list).  So you would drop the FeeParticularIdList column, and set up something like this:

```
create table FeePreference 
(
    Id tinyint not null,
    -- ... plus all the other columns
    constraint PK_FeePreference primary key nonclustered (Id)
);
create table FeeParticular
(
    Id smallint not null,
    -- plus all the other columns
    constraint PK_FeeParticular primary key nonclustered (Id)
);

create table PreferenceParticularMap
(
    FeePreferenceId tinyint not null,
    FeeParticularId smallint not null,
    constraint FK_PreferenceParticularMap_FeePreference foreign key (FeePreferenceId) references FeePreference (Id),
    constraint FK_PreferenceParticularMap_FeeParticular foreign key (FeeParticularId) references FeeParticular (Id)
);
```

Then your join doesn't have to deal with parsing out that string column:

```
select *
from FeePreference pref
    inner join PreferenceParticularMap map
        on pref.Id = map.FeePreferenceId
    inner join FeeParticular part
        on map.FeeParticularId = part.Id
```